# How to get Gamma function in Mathematica using Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

In Mathematica, `Gamma[a, z]` refers to the upper incomplete Gamma function whereas in Matlab, `gammainc(z, a)` refers to the regularized lower incomplete Gamma function. I want to know how I can obtain the Mathematica result using Matlab? In this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34628/gamma-incomplete-function-representation-in-mathematica-and-matlab), the method for obtaining same Matlab result using Mathematica was explained, but I couldn't find a strategy of getting one via Matlab.

Comment: Hi ! This is the *Matehmatica* SE, questions about *MATLAB* are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. In addition to the version offered by @MarkMcClure

```
y = (1-gammainc(z,a)).*gamma(a)
```

you can also use additional arguments to get the upper regularized gamma function directly:

```
y = gammainc(z,a,'upper').*gamma(a)
```

Note that the order of the arguments is opposite to that of Mathematica's function.

The above are strictly numeric functions, but Mathematica's `Gamma` evaluates symbolically. You can use Matlab's [`igamma`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/igamma.html) in the symbolic toolbox. Note that this function is not regularized and used the same argument order as Mathematica's function – it's as close to a direct equivalent as you'll find (but obviously slower for numeric evaluation):

```
syms a z;
y = igamma(a,z)
```

In older versions of Matlab, this function may not be directly available. You can however, still access the [MuPAD version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/igamma.html) via:

```
y = feval(symengine,'igamma',a,z)
```

or something like

```
y = evalin(symengine,['igamma(' char(a) ',' char(z) ')'])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia,

[image]

Thus, in Mathematica you might have

```
Gamma[1, 2] // N
```

While in Matlab you could have

```
gamma(1)-gammainc(2,1)
```

Both return 0.135335

Comment: FYI, as the OP stated, and as the documentation makes clear, Matlab's `gammainc` is regularized. The outputs only happen to turn out equal because `gamma(1) == 1`.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for pointing that out.  As an experienced Stackexchange user, I'm sure you're aware that small mistakes, such as a missing factor, are commonly dealt with via an edit, as opposed to an entirely new answer. Not that there's a whole lot of interest here; your only upvote after 9 hours is from me. :)

Comment: I apologize if you thought that I was correcting you in my answer. If you take a look at it, you'll see that I describe other options available to a Matlab user. I've updated my answer a bit. Personally, I prefer to let authors correct certain math/coding errors and only submit edits on things like important spelling errors, broken links, etc. And yes, even good questions/answers on StackOverflow/Matlab often get zeros votes. Sadly it's the short easy ones that seem to get voted up most here.